# Why does java return a 0?

Tags: java, netbeans

Why does `Java` return a `0` when I divide `10/60`?
the code I tried is

```
double pay_per_minute = (10/60);
```

10 being the pay rate per hour and 60 being the minutes.

Comment: 10 and 60 are integers, the result is 0 even before you convert to a double.

Comment: Following naming conventions is adviced - substitute `dayPerMinute` for `day_per_minute`. We're not doing <PHP5, right? ;)

Comment: Where is `dayPerMinute` on my question? can't see it.

Comment: As a warning, language like you used in your edit is completely unacceptable here. I've removed this.

Comment: I also notice that my (CW) answer was unaccepted. Was it a (badly aimed) attempt at taking a revenge against my close vote ? If so, you should dive deeper into SO and accept this was the correct output : you got downvotes because your question was easy to answer with a little search, and I voted to close, even while I answered to help you, because it *was* a duplicate.

Comment: @dystroy sorry thought i could delete the question to stop getting so much negative votes. Just accepted your answer again. can't use stackoverflow to ask questions again that's why i was away and forgot to accept your answer again my bad..

Comment: I've looked at some of your questions. I even upvoted one that wasn't bad. But the general feeling I got is that before asking SO you generally should google a little for tutorials/documentations on the topic you have a problem. Every time I ask SO, I spent hours searching before. To regain your ability to ask questions, you might try to answer some questions. Even if it isn't easy, you'll learn both the ways of SO and your languages (I learned, and still learn, a lot on SO by looking at questions and trying to answer).

Comment: Thank you!, will do, That's what I'm doing right at the moment researching everything I can before I go ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're building an integer. When you store it in a `double` variable, it's already too late : it's `0`.

Do

```
double pay_per_minute = (10.0/60);
```

If you have variables, cast them :

```
double pay_per_minute = ((double)pay_per_hour) / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

any primitive digit in java is treated as an integer, so when you do 10/60, it is integer division and due to precision loss it is giving 0

Answer (score 0):

Here `10` and `60` takes as int values and then you get `int` dividing result it is `0` then you get answer as `0`. use following way.

```
double a=10;
double b=60;

double div=a/b;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to type cast it first because by default numericals are considered as integers

```
double pay_per_minute = ((double)10/60);
    System.out.println(pay_per_minute);
```

**output** 0.16666666666666666

Answer (score 0):

```
double pay_per_minute = (10/60);
```

Here, you are dividing integer 10 by integer 60. So, this is like doing

```
int temp = 10/60;
double pay_per_minute = double(temp)
```

your temp will be 0 (since 10/60 is 0 when considered as integer division)

You need to do,
  double pay_per_minute = (10.0/60);